# Como puedo añadir datos al modelos sin usar un form

Tags: python, django, formularios, django-forms, django-views

Tengo una duda y necesito resolverla, veran trabajo en Django y tengo un formulario que guarda una serie utiles utilizando un campo ManyToMany de empleado mediante una tabla con checkbox, pero necesito que esos utiles individualmente se me actualizen en el modelo Utile cambiando su campo Entregado_A de False a True.

Estos son los Modelos

Utiles:

```html
lass Utile(models.Model):
    
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    um = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    existencia_sub_mayor = models.IntegerField()
    entrada = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    salida = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    existencia = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    precio_costo_prom = models.FloatField()
    importe = models.FloatField()
    referencia = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    externo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    entregado_a = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.codigo)
```

Empleado:

```html
class Empleado(models.Model):
    
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, null=True, blank=True )
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    utiles_herramientas = models.ManyToManyField(Utile)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.nombre, self.apellidos)
```

y esta es la View con la que gestiono la peticion y el Form donde se guarda utilizando los checkbox.

VIEW:

```html
class UtilesExternosUpdate(UpdateView):
    
    model = Empleado
    form_class = EmpleadoForm
    template_name = 'app/externos_por_area.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy ('app:empleados')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UtilesExternosUpdate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        area = Area.objects.get(pk= self.object.area_id)
        utiles = Utile.objects.filter(area_id= area.pk, externo = True, entregado_a = False)
        print(utiles)
        kwargs.update({'utiles': utiles})

        return kwargs
```

FORM:

```html
class EmpleadoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    utiles_herramientas = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=None,
        widget=TableSelectMultiple(
           item_attrs=[
               'area','codigo','descripcion',
               
           ],
           enable_shift_select=True,
           enable_datatables=True,
           bootstrap_style=True,
           #datatable_options={'language': {'url': '/foobar.js'}},
            )
    
    )
    def __init__(self,queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
        util = kwargs.pop('utiles')
        super(EmpleadoForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields["utiles_herramientas"].queryset = util

        

    class Meta:
        model = Empleado
        fields = [
            
            'utiles_herramientas'
        ]
        labels = {
            
            'utiles_herramientas': 'Útiles y Herramientas'

        }
```

Tengo la idea de utilizar los utiles que se entregan que se recogen en los Kwargs en la vista y mediante un for y el id de cada util, cambiarle el parametro al campo Entregado_A del modelo Utile, pero no se muy bien como hacerlo. Tenia la idea de un formset rondandome la cabeza pero no creo que aplique.

y a partir de ahora empiezo a escribir cualquier cosa para que stackoverflow me deje publicar la pregunta xq me dice que a;ada mas detalles y no me queda mas nada que decir.

Comment: No has intentado sobreescribir el método `save` del formulario a fin de ejecutar ese proceso cuando se llama al `save` en el classView?

Answer (score 0):

La solución sería simple, no usar métodos basados en clases, si no funciones, para simplificar el código y no tener que estar haciendo overrides, si no centrarte únicamente en lo que quieres.

Validas el formulario, si es correcto `empleado = empleado_form.save(commit=False)` y ya puedes navegar por `empleado` para setearle lo que necesites. En tu caso, recorrer `empleado.utiles` y ponerle a cada uno `entregado_a = True`. Por último, `empleado.save()`.